# Why processing arrays in F# is faster than lists

Tags: arrays, list, f#

I was checking the performance of F# lists and arrays. Given the code:

```
let list = [ 1.. 100000 ]
for i in 1 .. 100 do ignore ( list|>List.map(fun n -> n))

let array = [| 1.. 100000 |]
for i in 1 .. 100 do ignore ( array|>Array.map(fun n -> n))
```

I would suspect both to run in very similar time. Actually it turned out that arrays are over 10 times faster : array takes 28 ms while list takes 346 ms!
Why is that? I understand the concept of list in F# and the fact that for example appending values to list or taking subsequence is time consuming but in this code it just iterates through all elements so I thought the timing will be very comparable.

Tests under release mode in Visual Studio 2012 (in Debug mode arrays are about 5 times faster).

Comment: I just love getting negative votes without any (constructive) comments.

Comment: I would be curious what you'd see if you used a Seq in your tests (no joke).  Since Seq's are lazy should be practically instantaneous.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The main difference is that arrays are allocated as a continuous block of memory - the `Array.map` function knows the size of the input array and can perform just a single allocation to get all memory for the resulting array. On the other hand, the `List.map` function needs to separately allocate a single "cons cell" for each element of the input array.

The difference is particularly visible for the `map` function, because that can really benefit from the up-front allocation. However, arrays are generally faster for larger data sets. If you change the code to use filtering (where the array needs to be reallocated during construction), then the array version is ~2x faster:

```
for i in 1 .. 100 do ignore ( list|>List.filter(fun n -> n%5=1))
for i in 1 .. 100 do ignore ( array|>Array.map(fun n -> n%5=1))
```

Using lists has other benefits - because they are immutable, you can safely share references to lists. Also, cloning a list and adding an element to the front is super efficient (single cell allocation), while doing similar operation with array would be really slow (copy the whole array).

Comment: So it's just the initialization. When I measure just the projection lists are slightly faster.

Comment: This may be lame question, but there isn't probably way to initialize the list in fast manner in F#, is there (is it even possible with any other funcional language)? The thing is that I can easily compute the exact size of collections I am working with (many of them). Up to now I was using lists since all of them are used using iterative manner and lists are much more elegant in F#, I think.

Comment: Might compiling to release rather than debug also make a difference? If I recall correctly a lot of things like these get heavily optimized in a full release build (like tail recursion, for example).

Comment: That's right tail recursion is working only with Release. But in this case as I wrote in the question, compiling to release only slightly improves Lists performance (while arrays performance is improved over two times)

Comment: It is not just the initialization, traversing the array will also be faster, as contiguous memory will get cached in the CPU's L1, L2 and L3 (if it exists) caches, which can make a *Tremendous* difference. So much so that even if you do a few clones or adds to an Array, it will tend to still be faster if you also have to iterate over the collection. This difference can be hidden with toy examples as the heap will be free and empty and list nodes will tend to be allocated contiguously as well.